# Immediate rendering to GLKView

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkview

Let's say I have some C++ code that renders stuff in OpenGL ES. This code has it's own render loop which is the same on all platforms. One of the things that are OS dependent and have to be written for each platform separately is creating a window that is linked to an OpenGL context that is then used for drawing. I used the `GLKView` placed as a subview to the `UIWindow` but from what I've noticed the first attempt to render results in nothing and all that is visible for a while is a black screen.

The next iterations of the loop however render just fine. To see the problem more clearly here is a minimal code that behaves similarly:

```
EAGLContext *context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES3];
assert(context);

GLKView *glView = [[GLKView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self window] frame] context:context];
[[self window] addSubview:glView];

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

prepareOpengl();
drawTriangle(); //GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION

[self performSelector:@selector(drawTriangleWithContext:) withObject:context afterDelay:1.0]; //nice triangle
```

The `prepareOpengl()` function creates the buffers for vertices and whatnot and the `drawTraingle()` clears the buffers and draws a traingle. The first call results in `GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION` and the one called by `performSelector:afterDelay:` draws just fine. This probably means that the `GLKView` defers the creation of it's renderbuffer.

I would really like to not have to wait for the first rendering and instead be able to draw immediately to the created context. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hxougezgg2n01b6/iOS%20OpenGL.zip?dl=0) is the whole demo project that shows the issue.

Comment: GLKView might not be the best idea in this case. And since you are injecting this over the whole application I would suggest you to move the whole thing to another context on another thread and draw it to the FBO,  then on main thread redraw it to your main buffer. Also watch out if the app is already using some context so you should check what is the current context, set yours as current, do your work, set the previous context as current. But here I guess the buffer is not yet generated. Try setNeedsDisplay, displayIfNeeded and glFlush if any of these fixes your issue.

Comment: @MaticOblak This example just reflects the behaviour. The real code would be much different but still suffer from the fact that the buffer is only generated after a while. The solutions You proposed did not change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. The trick is to explicitly call `bindDrawable` on the `GLKView` after creating it. This in turn forces the creation of the  renderbuffer.

This is how it should be:

```
GLKView *glView = [[GLKView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self window] frame] context:context];
[glView bindDrawable];
[[self window] addSubview:glView];

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context]
prepareOpengl();
drawTriangle();
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```